# How do I pass multiple Items into an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Currently I have an custom adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter`. Within my `ListView`, I have an `ImageView` called `photo` for contact photos, **3** `TextViews` for contact names (`contactName`), message (`contactMSG`), and a counter (`contactMSGcounter`). My constructor thats passed into my Activity that holds my `ListView` so far looks like this:

```
// newlist contains all queried contacts
CustomAdapter cAdapt = new CustomAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newlist);
```

This only takes in an `ArrayList` of contact names.

From the developer site, there are many different constructors I could use:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

How can I pass all the above objects into my constructor? I'm assuming `T[] objects` is the possible solution, but if this is true, how do I use this?

Comment: I would make an object that encapsulates all of the data you have and pass an an ArrayList of that object, instead of an ArrayList of strings containing names.

Comment: @Tim do you know of a tutorial I can follow? I haven't done this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpicyWeenie,

To provide your adapter with certain data, you can use a *POJO*.

Create a simple class with some properties & functionality and make a list of this object.

```
ArrayList<MyContactObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyContactObject>();
```

To fill your list with your contacts, you can make use the [Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) (Android below 2.0) or [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) (Android 2.0 and above) classes. 
An example on how to read out your contacts you can find here: [Link](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/)

Like jack57 said, you can make yourself a custom XML to provide your desired layouts. Another link, I think you might find useful is the following: [logc.at](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/). They have a great and clean implementation of a ListView. Try to follow the structure cause it is simple and easy to maintain.

Good luck!

Comment: I already have the XML layout for each item created. I cant find a tutorial for what jack57 said.

Comment: You can find a tutorial here at bullet [6. ListActivity with own layout](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.htm).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an XML resource with those Text and Image Views you mentioned formatted the way you wish.
2. Pass the XML id in, ex. R.id.myXml, and there ya go.
3. Inside the CustomAdapter, take care of business by calling the views using findByViewId, and you're all set.

Comment: Im not quite understanding how to come about this concept

Comment: I think I misunderstood you as well.  I would employ three synchronized ArrayLists and make your adapter a private helper class in your original Activity.  Then the adapter can access all three of them  using the same index.

Comment: Tim makes a good point as well, making an object called ContactData that contains all of that information would be much cleaner